# Issue while deploying nodejs app to Openshift using Cloud9IDE

Tags: node.js, openshift, cloud9-ide

I am trying to deploy a node.js app to Openshift using cloud9IDE and i am getting this following error and the application is not deployed

```
[1/4] Verifying preconditions...
[2/4] Updating repository...
[3/4] Pushing to OpenShift...
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://51f125624382ecc94000009a@appname.rhcloud.com/~/git/appname.git/'
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://51f125624382ecc94000009a@appname.rhcloud.com/~/git/appname.git/'
[4/4] Deploy succeeded
```

did anyone faced such issue ever??

Answer (score 0):

There are some suggestions here, see if any of them help you.

[git: error: src refspec master does not match any](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568641/git-error-src-refspec-master-does-not-match-any)