# Syncing GIT : refspec master does not match any

Tags: git, bash, version-control, synchronization

I am trying to get a number of GIT repositories sync-ed with ours. As these projects come and go I decided to create one single script that I call with a CronTab in order to preform the script.

I did try this by hand and it did work, however with these other repositories it did not.

My Bash Script:

```
external_repos=( "OurName.projectx" "OurName.anotherproject" "OurName.thirdproject" "OurName.stackexchange" )

for i in "${external_repos[@]}"
do
        echo "Handling"  $i

        TEMP=`echo $i | cut -d "." -f 2`
        TEMP="${TEMP^}"
        REPO="EXTERNAL-REPO-$TEMP"

#       printf "Temp : %s\n" $TEMP
#       printf "Repo : %s\n" $REPO

        if [ -d "$i" ]; then
                pushd $i 
                git pull external_developer develop && git push origin master
                popd
        else
                git clone https://extern_u:$3cret@bitbucket.org/external/$i.git
                pushd $i
                git remote rename origin external_developer
                git remote add origin http://APIUser:P@s$w0rd@repo.ourdomain.com/scm/git/$REPO
                git push origin master
                popd
        fi
done
```

Everything goes perfectly, till the git part.. Cloning works. remote rename works remote add works but the git push gives me an error:

```
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'http:http://APIUser:P@s$w0rd@repo.ourdomain.com/scm/git/EXTERNAL-REPO-Projectx'
```

This error means that master does not exist external right? But as far as I know it does exist. Also I've read:
[Git push existing repo to a new and different remote repo server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181845/git-push-existing-repo-to-a-new-and-different-remote-repo-server)
and 
[Push origin master error on new repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827351/push-origin-master-error-on-new-repository)

After this I did some more research into git and I figured that the externals use a branch named develop and main is just for the initial commit.

Am I making some huge Git Error? How can I fix this issue or is there a better way to Sync two gits?

Before I forget:
 I tried to add all and I tried a commit before.

Thus I've read:
[src refspec master does not match any when pushing commits in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181861/src-refspec-master-does-not-match-any-when-pushing-commits-in-git)
and
[git: error: src refspec master does not match any](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568641/git-error-src-refspec-master-does-not-match-any)

Comment: does it work for you, if you do it by hands?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ One of the repos did work, all the other. Did not and give this error.

Comment: try to do pull before push, on others

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ Same error. The pull results in a 'Already up-to-date.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved, the external party did not have a master branch. Only a develop branch.

```
external_repos=( "OurName.projectx" "OurName.anotherproject" "OurName.thirdproject" "OurName.stackexchange" )

for i in "${external_repos[@]}"
do
        echo "Handling"  $i

        TEMP=`echo $i | cut -d "." -f 2`
        TEMP="${TEMP^}"
        REPO="EXTERNAL-REPO-$TEMP"

#       printf "Temp : %s\n" $TEMP
#       printf "Repo : %s\n" $REPO

        if [ -d "$i" ]; then
                pushd $i 
                git pull external_developer develop && git push origin develop
                popd
        else
                git clone https://extern_u:$3cret@bitbucket.org/external/$i.git
                pushd $i
                git remote rename origin external_developer
                git remote add origin http://APIUser:P@s$w0rd@repo.ourdomain.com/scm/git/$REPO
                git push origin develop
                popd
        fi
done
```