# Drupal 7 uploading first sandbox module using Git Bash

Tags: git, bash, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I am uploading my first sandbox module on **drupal 7** but facing some errors.Here are steps i followed according to drupal api.
Under version control tab i found that peace of git instructions and commands to follow.

```
mkdir my_module_name

cd my_module_name

git init

git checkout -b 7.x-1.x

echo "name = my_module_name" > my_module_name.info

git add my_module_name.info

git commit -m "Initial commit."

git remote add origin userxxx@git.drupal.org:sandbox/userxxx/xxxxxx.git

git push origin 7.x-1.x
```

When i ran these commands using **git bash** i got error something like this.

```
error: src refspec 7.x-1.x does not match any.<br />
error: failed to push some refs to 'userxxx@git.drupal.org:sandbox/userxxx/xxxxxx.git'
```

What i am missing here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to tell git what remote ref to push to. It doesn't have an upstream ref yet.

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit more??Thank you!

Comment: **Solved**
found help at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/827351/push-origin-master-error-on-new-repository

Answer (score 1):

A general solution is to maintain (the correct order of) commands:

```
git add (to be added files)
git commit -m 'message'
git push origin master --force
```

[Syncing GIT : refspec master does not match any](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21825601) gave me also some great insights on how to tackle it!