# Git: git push -u origin origin:master

Tags: git, github, version-control

So I have problem listed in title.

I want to use just `git push -u origin master`.

But if this command typed I'm getting:

```
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/myprofile/my_project.git'
```

I did a search on this problem([git: error: src refspec master does not match any](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568641/git-error-src-refspec-master-does-not-match-any), [src refspec master does not match any when pushing commits in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181861/src-refspec-master-does-not-match-any-when-pushing-commits-in-git)) - but solutions didn't help in my case.

Seems like I just forget to do some initial commit to original remote branch and instead created another branch which then was used.

This is output from `git ls-remote`:

```
$ git ls-remote
From https://github.com/myprofile/my_project.git
152e795f054f6f756842bf61ee968ba3e5ee873d        HEAD
7d505dbf09585ecfbb239c2148337043b899cc13        refs/heads/add-mysql-repo
152e795f054f6f756842bf61ee968ba3e5ee873d        refs/heads/break-into-modules
e7905a3dacc9ea3e6c4c1f2dd9412f8deb692e30        refs/heads/master
```

This is github graph's network window:
[image: my_project branches]

So to sum up - what should I do to properly use `git push -u origin master` instead `git push -u origin origin:master` ?

**EDIT:**

$ git branch -avv

```
  add-mysql-repo        7d505db add mysql case to switch
  break-into-modules    152e795 add gitignore
* origin                e7905a3 [origin/master] add methods for entities validation
  remotes/origin/master e7905a3 add methods for entities validation
```

$ git remote -v

```
origin  https://github.com/myprofile/my_project.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/myprofile/my_project.git (push)
```

Comment: What `git branch -avv` return? And `git remote -v`?

Comment: @VonC I add output from this commands. Please take a look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering the output of `git branch -avv`:

- you don't have a local branch named `master`,
- you have a branch with the same name as `origin` (a remote referencing the **[upstream repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2749166/6309)**).

That means you should:

- [rename the branch origin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6591218/6309):

  ```
  git branch -m origin master
  ```
- push normally

  ```
  git push -u origin master
  ```

Comment: Yes, I tested your solution and it helped. Thanks !