# error in pushing to master: git

Tags: git

I am a new git user.

I have a repository on bitbucket that I would like to import into a .git folder I have created on my live shared host web server ( where I have git installed ). I can give commands via SSH. I am following the instructions in http://joemaller.com/990/a-web-focused-git-workflow/

I have been able to set up the 2 repos on the server as described in the article. However when give the command:

```
"git remote add hub ~/site_hub.git; git remote show hub; git push hub master; "
```

I get:

```
Push URL: /home/***/site_hub.git HEAD branch: (unknown) 
error: src refspec master does not match any. 
error: failed to push some refs to '/home/***/site_hub.git'
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot push to an empty repository: it doesn't contain yet a `master` branch.

For bare repo, try a:

```
git push -u origin master
```

This is because of a recent **[push policy change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586687/what-is-the-result-of-git-push-origin/9749477#9749477)**.

In your case, your remote bare repo is called hub, so:

```
git push -u hub master
```

The [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1592380/user61629) still get an error:

```
src refspec master does not match any. 
error: failed to push some refs to '/home/*****/site_hub.git
```

But that is the case only if no commits were ever done on master of the source repo.
And indeed, the [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1592380/user61629) reports:

> I had a syntax error error, preventing the add command from working in the 'prime' repository.
>   After fixing this the files appeared to add correctly. I then ran '`git push hub master`' and there now appear to be files in the `site_hub.git/objects/pack` directory which I assume are the pushed files.

---

For non-bare repo, make an empty commit first in the destination local repo.

See, for concrete examples:

- "[`push origin master` error on new repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827351/push-origin-master-error-on-new-repository)"
- "[`src refspec master` does not match any when pushing commits in git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7572252/6309)"

Comment: Now I tried: cd site_hub.git; touch README; git add README; git commit -m 'first commit'; but I get: fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree .what have I done wrong?

Comment: @user61629 right, this is a bare repo, so no commit possible directly in it. I have updated my answer. If it is not working, try changing  the push policy.

Comment: I tried, git push -u origin master

I am now getting: fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly. I am wondering if it should be git push -u hub master in this case based on the article?

Comment: I tried to checkout the master branch while in the prime directory. This gives: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.so it seems that master branch is not defined?

Comment: from the prime directory as in the article. git remote -v show gives:  hub /home/*****/site_hub.git (fetch) hub /home/*****/site_hub.git (push)

Comment: @user61629 right, I didn't see at first your remote repo was called `hub`. So what does `git push -u hub master` does?

Comment: output: src refspec master does not match any. error: failed to push some refs to '/home/*****/site_hub.git

Comment: @user61629 that message would only possible if you don't have any commit or master branch on your *source* Git repo (the one your are pushing from).

Comment: VonC, I am oficially an idiot. I had a syntax error error, preventing the add command from working in the 'prime' repository. after fixing this the files appeared to add correctly. I then ran 'git push hub master' and there now appear to be files in the site_hub.git/objects/pack directory which I assume are the pushed files. Once again thank you for your help , I am going to continue to follow the articles directions, and I'll open a new question if I can't figure something else out. Regards, - Bill

Comment: @user61629 No problem, I am glad you made it work in the end :) I would  still recommend a git push -u hub master instead of a git push hub master though: that *upstream* tacking link is important. I have edited the answer to reflect your conclusion for more visibility.