# Git add all files modified, deleted, and untracked?

Tags: git, git-add, git-rm

Is there a way to add all files no matter what you do to them whether it be deleted, untracked, etc? like for a commit. I just don't want to have to `git add` or `git rm` all my files every time I commit, especially when I'm working on a large product.

Comment: See: [Difference of “git add -A” and “git add .”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572549/difference-of-git-add-a-and-git-add)

Answer (score 328):

Try:

```
git add -A
```

---

**Warning:** Starting with git 2.0 (mid 2013), this will **always** stage files **on the whole working tree**.
If you want to stage files under the current path of your working tree, you need to use:

```
git add -A .
```

Also see: [Difference of `git add -A` and `git add .`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16162511/6309)

Comment: this did not work for me... how can i show my terminal input-output in this discussion? copy-paste my terminal output as an answer to this discussion?

Comment: here is the problem i am facing - http://stackoverflow.com/q/7726131/636762 - kindly help me on this one please

Comment: This can also not work if your git version is old.  I was running a script on a server that was running git 1.5.2.5.  git add -A was not working.  From the script, no error message was reported.  Only from the command line did I find that -A was not a legal option to add.

Comment: but why do i have to add files everytime I want to make a commit!? Everytime I made changes to a files to I need to add it..

Comment: This is just how Git works. You have to add changes to your staging area before you commit it. For example, you can add only some files to a commit and provide comments for it, instead of all files all the time. Here's a handy explanation of what this is doing and why: http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/01/18/the-staging-area.html

Answer (score 79):

Try

```
git add -u
```

The "`u`" option stands for update.  This will update the repo and actually delete files from the repo that you have deleted in your local copy.

```
git add -u [filename]
```

to stage a delete to just one file.  Once pushed, the file will no longer be in the repo.

Alternatively,

`git add -A .`

is equivalent to

```
git add .

git add -u .
```

Note the extra '.' on `git add -A` and `git add -u`

---

**Warning:** Starting with git 2.0 (mid 2013), this will **always** stage files **on the whole working tree**.
If you want to stage files under the current path of your working tree, you need to use:

```
git add -A .
```

Also see: [Difference of `git add -A` and `git add .`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16162511/6309)

Answer (score 57):

The following answer only applies to Git version 1.x, but to Git version 2.x.

You want `git add -A`:

`git add -A` stages All;

`git add .` stages new and modified, without deleted;

`git add -u` stages modified and deleted, without new.

Comment: Note the above only applies to Git 1.x. For git version 2.x, `git add -A` is equivalent to `git add .`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572549/difference-between-git-add-a-and-git-add) for more discussions.

Answer (score 32):

`git add --all` **or** `git add -A` **or** `git add -A .` **Stages All**

`git add .` **Stages New & Modified** But ***Without Deleted***

`git add -u` **Stages Modified & Deleted** But ***Without New***

`git commit -a` Means `git add -u` And `git commit -m "message"`

After writing this command follow these steps:-

1. press <kbd>i</kbd>
2. write your message
3. press <kbd>esc</kbd>
4. press <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>
5. press <kbd>enter</kbd>

`git add <list of files>` add specific file

`git add *.txt` add all the txt files in current directory

`git add docs/*/txt`  add all txt files in docs directory

`git add docs/`  add all files in docs directory

`git add "*.txt"` or `git add '*.txt'` add all the files in the whole project

Answer (score 13):

I'm not sure if it will add deleted files, but `git add .` from the root will add all untracked files.

Comment: see my answer on how to add deleted files

Answer (score 6):

For **newer version** of Git.

I tried `git add -A` and this prompted,

> warning: The behavior of 'git add --all (or -A)' with no path argument
>   from a subdirectory of the tree will change in Git 2.0 and should not
>   be used anymore. To add content for the whole tree, run:
>
> git add --all :/   (or git add -A :/)
>
> To restrict the command to the current directory, run:
>
> git add --all .   (or git add -A .)
>
> With the current Git version, the command is restricted to the current
>   directory.

Then I tried below which **worked**.

```
git add --all :/
```

Answer (score 5):

I authored the G2 project, a friendly environment for the command line git lover.
   Please get the project from github - G2 https://github.com/orefalo/g2

It has a bunch of handy commands, one of them being exactly what your are looking for: `freeze`

**freeze** - Freeze all files in the repository (additions, deletions, modifications) to the staging area, thus staging that content for inclusion in the next commit. Also accept a specific path as parameter

Answer (score 5):

This is my alternative (in any bash):

```
$ git status -s|awk '{ print $2 }'|xargs git add
```

To reset

```
$ git status -s|awk '{ print $2 }'|xargs git reset HEAD
```

Answer (score 4):

I use the following line to add for staging all the modified and newly created files, excluding the ones listed in .gitignore:

```
git add $(git ls-files -mo --exclude-standard)
```

(the syntax $() is for the bash shell).  I guess that the command line option -mod should add also the deleted files...  Or, if you have file names with embedded blanks, the following one-liner should do the trick:

```
git ls-files -z --deleted --modified --others --exclude-standard | xargs -0 git add
```

Answer (score 3):

From Git documentation starting from version 2.0:

To add content for the whole tree, run:

```
git add --all :/
```

or

```
git add -A :/
```

To restrict the command to the current directory, run:

```
git add --all .
```

or

```
git add -A .
```