# Git Not Committing Directory Contents

Tags: git, git-commit, git-add

I'm trying to add every single thing I have in directory through git.  However, for one particular directory, it loads the folder, but none of the contents.  I tried to use

```
git add -A
```

but was returned

```
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#   (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
#
#   modified:   sendgrid-php (untracked content)
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

upon trying to commit my changes.  What could be the problem here?

Comment: Maybe your .gitignore file is ignoring the folder or its content.

Comment: possible duplicate of [git add -A is not adding all modified files in directories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726131/git-add-a-is-not-adding-all-modified-files-in-directories)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directory `sendgrid-php` is git submodule, so git will not track content inside it, unless you will CD into it and commit them.

Comment: I tried to commit while in the subdirectory, I'm told I'm ahead by one commit, and that I have nothing to commit.

Comment: Have you staged changes in subdirectory (via git add -A) ?

Comment: Yeah, I do that and still get the # On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)'

Comment: CD back to your project directory, there shouldn't be any untracked content now.

Comment: I CD into the subdirectory, run 'git add .' , CD out into the project directory, try to commit, and get '# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)' . This also happens when I run 'git add -A'.  However, when I navigate to my domain, and then add '/send-grid.php', all it shows is a hyperlink to 'Parent_directory'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24678/discussion-between-user1114864-and-mpogoda)

Answer (score 1):

One possible way would be

```
git add directory/*
```

or if you have already commited files from that directory before you can just make a

```
git commit -a
```

That will add and commit all modified files.

Comment: When using your first suggestion, I get 'fatal: Path 'sendgrid-php/MIT.LICENSE' is in submodule 'sendgrid-php''

Comment: Do you have another git repo in the directory 'sendgrid-php'? The error message suggests that that directory is part of a git submodule (http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules).

Comment: I think I may, but I'm not sure how to address it in terms of committing it.