# Why git fails silently adding a specific untracked file?

Tags: git

I am trying to add a specific untracked file for the next commit in the local repository with `git add myfile`. When I do, it behaves like if it worked (no output). But, if I execute `git status`, the file is still untracked. The file itself is nothing esoteric, just a python script. This failure didn't happen with other python scripts in the same branch.

I've searched for similar questions in StackOverflow as far as I was able to, this is the most similar I could find: [Why git add -A didn't add these files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27673297/why-git-add-a-didnt-add-these-files) But, this case is significantly different from mine. I also found [this bug report](http://lists-archives.com/git/717612-git-add-device-file-silently-fails.html) on Google, but I wasn't able to understand the only answer to that bug issue.

I am using git 2.1.0 in Ubuntu 14.04. I moved the repository several weeks ago to another machine following @bdonlan 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1484653/3692177) in [How to migrate GIT repository from one server to a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484648/how-to-migrate-git-repository-from-one-server-to-a-new-one): "Copy it over. It's really that simple. :)". Everything worked fine until now, except this issue.

Is there a way to find out why is this happening?

Comment: Whats the name of the file? Does this happen with another newly created file with the same name? Does it happen with a newly created file with the same content as the existing one?

Comment: Maybe you have permissions/user problem?

Comment: @Nikolai No. The permissions were the same for other python scripts, and they were added successfully.

Comment: @ThomasS I don't know why you are asking for the filename actually, but the only special char it has (just in case the information may be useful) is a "_" used twice. But this char was used in other files that were succesfully added to commit.

Comment: Indeed, try to add same file with a different name. Or same file in a different path.

Comment: Casually, I was having the same idea right now. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Could the filename have gained a space or other unprintable character (or even a unicode char)? Maybe you should quote the filename just to be sure.

Comment: who knows, maybe they were Unicode... anyway it ts strange, the name just used english letters, the "_" char and numbers. Anyway **changing the name fixed the problem**, and the only thing I did was just adding a char to the previous name. Thank you. Maybe you want to post it as an answer....

Comment: Something very strange keeps happening: now I can add the file to a commit, but the old name is still in the list of untracked files...

Comment: Do you have a .gitignore file?  If so, what is in it?

Comment: Yeah, I made a .gitignore to prevent the tracking of *.pyc and *.pyo files.