# git add --foldername fails to include submodules

Tags: git, github, repository, branch

In my git repository I created a branch, call it feature/blah. feature/blah is intended to contain 3 submodules and some other associated files that are not at all present on the master branch yet.

The three submodules are located in a directory called `containers\`

I created the branch in git via `git checkout -b feature/blah`

Then i see that my current branch is the branch i just created, as intended.

As per this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726131/git-add-a-is-not-adding-all-modified-files-in-directories) I then enter the containers\ directory that has my three submodules with intention to add each one individually because they act as independent repositories according to that link.

However, once I enter `containers\` to add submodules container_a, container_b, container_c, I see that my branch has switched back to master, and not feature/blah.

When I `cd ..` back out, I am back to feature/blah

I want those three submodules to each be nested under my containers directory, and I want them to be on my feature/blah branch. Is this possible? There is a larger reason the submodules are all nested under the containers/ directory, but if this is the heart of the issue I can work around it.

Thanks again for any help.

Comment: looks like you created one single submodule for `container` instead of separate submodules in `container/a`, `container/b` and `container/c`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So you are saying I need to either integrate an __init__ .py file in my container\ directory, or I can't do this?