# How do I add a folder to an existing git project at the project's root?

Tags: git, commit, subdirectory

I'm using Git on Mac OS X.  I have a folder at the root of my project (at the same level as the ".git" folder) and I want to add it so I tried

```
localhost:salesproject satishp$ git add -A myfolder1/
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in server.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in web/processor.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
```

However when I ran

```
localhost:salesproject satishp$ git commit -m 'Some changes.'
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in server.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in web/processor.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
    modified:   myfolder1 (modified content)

no changes added to commit
```

Despite the fact there were changes in this folder.  Following this advice -- [git add -A is not adding all modified files in directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726131/git-add-a-is-not-adding-all-modified-files-in-directories) , I tried this

```
localhost:salesproject satishp$ git submodule foreach --recursive git add -A .
Entering 'myfolder1'
No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'myfolder1'
```

but I still get the same error when I try and commit.  How do I add my directory to my Git project?

**Edit:** Here's what happens when I run "git status"

```
localhost:salesproject satishp$ git status myfolder1/
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in server.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in web/processor.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)

    modified:   myfolder1 (modified content)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: What is the content of `myfolder1`? What is the output of `git status` after `git add -A myfolder1`?

Comment: 'Despite the fact there were changes in this folder" How can there be changes if you haven't committed the folder before? Do you mean to say that it has content?

Comment: @mkrieger1, I added the output in response to the "git status" command (executed after the git add -A command you recommended I run)

Comment: you should be able to just add that particular folder with git i.e. : `git add myfolder1` ; also, supposing the folder isn't empty (if it's empty, that might be the reason, not sure about if you have hidden files in it).

Comment: You issue might actually be this: `No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'myfolder1'` ; some articles I've found point to do an update / init of the git submodule `git submodule update --init` (do pls  RTFM before using: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) ;then doing a `git rm --cached myfolder1`/
You should then be able to `git add myfolder1 ; git commit -m "etc"`

Comment: @Sanda, THis last sequence -- starting with your "git rm --cached myfodler1") worked.

Comment: happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You issue might actually be this:
`No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'myfolder1'`

1. Some articles I've found point to do an update / init of the git submodule git submodule update --init (do pls RTFM before using: git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule);
2. Then do a `git rm --cached myfolder1`
3. You should then be able to
   `git add myfolder1 ; git commit -m "etc"`

(just transcribing the response from the comments)