# git add . vs git commit -a

Tags: version-control, git-commit, git-add, git

What's the difference between:

- `git add .`
- `git commit -a`

Should I be doing both, or is that redundant?

Comment: see also (not exact duplicate, though): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572549/difference-of-git-add-a-and-git-add

Answer (score 163, accepted):

`git commit -a` means almost[*] the same thing as `git add -u && git commit`.

It's not the same as `git add .` as this would add untracked files that aren't being ignored, `git add -u` only stages changes (including deletions) to already tracked files.

[*] There's a subtle difference if you're not at the root directory of your repository. `git add -u` stages updates to files in the current directory and below, it's equivalent to `git add -u .` whereas `git commit -a` stages and commits changes to *all* tracked files.

Comment: The behaviour in [*] will change in git 2.0, for consistency.

Comment: In which direction? i.e. will commit -a become like add -u, or will add -u become like commit -a?

Comment: @MilesRout: `git add -u` will become like `git commit -a`; you will need to explicitly say `git add -u .` if that is what you mean.

Comment: This is absolutely the same since Git v 2.0 where [`git add .` behaves in a different way.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16162511/2790048)

Answer (score 15):

`git commit -a` automatically invokes `git add` on all files it knows about. You can use `git add` to select what files to commit. Consult the docs for more info: [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit)

Comment: *all files it knows about* is very unclear to me, especially since those were supposedly NOT added

Comment: @Nikana Reklawyks You have the definition of "add" wrong. Add does not mean the same thing as it does in svn. All it does is update the index. [Sorry for slow response, I don't remember getting a notification for that comment]

Comment: @alternative, Still this answer can do better if you add a clarification for "all files it knows about".....

Comment: @Pacerier equivalent to `git add -u`

Comment: "all files it knows about" vaguely speaking would be existing files that were modified. Or, NOT new files.

Comment: @Z.Khullah, so "all (...)" means "tracked files"?

Comment: @TheFrost precisely!

Answer (score 2):

By using the git commit -a switch with the commit command to automatically "add" changes from all known files (i.e. all files that are already listed in the index)