# Git expects numerical timeout?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, timeout, push, pull

Working on a project in IntelliJ and pushing/pulling all material to github.

Suddenly it stops working: I tried to fetch the code from github and get the error message:
Fetch failed
Error: option 'timeout' expects a numerical value

Similar error messages have occurred whenever I tried to push, but ultimately the push always went through. Until now, when I suddenly get the message

Push rejected
Master: rejected

I'm really inexperienced with git, any answers are helpful!

```
cd coding
git pull

Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details

git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

git branch --set-upstream master origin/<branch>
```

When I try to pull and

```
git push
error: option `timeout' expects a numerical value
usage: git credential-cache [options] <action>

--timeout <n>         number of seconds to cache credentials
--socket <path>       path of cache-daemon socket

Everything up-to-date
```

The problem is everything ISN'T up to date

Hey guys, appreciate all the help, turned out that the error was something very simple that was overlooked during the setup of git on my machine.

https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git

If anyone else has problems like the ones mentioned above, there's one thing you can try. Afterwards a pull-merge and then push worked fine.

Comment: Is your remote repository a bare repo?

Comment: Does it work from the command line?

Comment: I put up the code, as well as the messages that came up in terminal

Answer (score 2):

If something related to GitHub suddenly stop working, then it is probably linked to [its status](https://status.github.com/messages).

> 6:24 UTC A small percentage of repositories are currently unavailable while we perform maintenance.

If it does persist though, then it could be related with some local configuration issue.

For instance, check `git status` and `git branch`, making sure you are on a branch, and not in a [detached HEAD mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965676/why-did-git-detach-my-head/3965714#3965714).

If `git status` mentions files to be committed (ie they have been added to [the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4086986/6309) but not yet registered ion a commit), do a [`git commit` after your `git add`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3541655/6309).

If `git branch` doesn't return anything, then you need to follow "[Git: How can I reconcile detached HEAD with `master/origin`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5772882/6309)"

Comment: Started having these problems yesterday though

Comment: @scibor are you in a detached head branch like my edited answer suggests?

Comment: That seems like it could be the problem, but I'm really not sure how to check, could you maybe elaborate a bit? Sorry, I'm just really new to git

Comment: @scibor if git status returns "no branch", with a list of branch without one with a '`*`' in front of it, you are in a detached head. See the link in my answer. And then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471300/git-switch-branch-without-detaching-head to solve this.

Comment: Typing git status yielded

Initial Commit ->
Changes to be committed 

->list of files

Comment: Typed "git branch" no output

Comment: @scibor I have edited the answer, with a link to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772192/git-how-can-i-reconcile-detached-head-with-master-origin in order to reconcile the detached head with a branch. It is strange that you have no *local* branch though. `git branch -a` should list your remote branch(es) as well, assuming your local repo is the clone of a github repo.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should set a timeout like:

git config credential.helper 'cache --timeout == 3600'