# Why `commit` is needed before `git checkout`?

Tags: git

I thought `git add` is enough to log the modifies made before `checkout` to another branch.

Therefore, why do the modifies should be logged to local repository by `commit`?

Comment: `git commit` is what actually saves the snapshot. `git add` composes it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git add . vs git commit -a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541647/git-add-vs-git-commit-a)

Answer (score 1):

It's because you can patch diffs in and out of your staged content in both directions, from history or from your work tree, at any time. Commit says "yep, this whole set is worth revisiting later", but before then it's still actively being edited, by you.

`git add` doesn't have to be treated as provisional; for people unused to thinking of their vcs as a tool helping them iterate drafts of the history they're eventually going to publish it seems weird and unnecessary. Once you start thinking of your local history as a whole-tree, long-term extension of your editor's undo buffers it makes much more sense. Git helps you do the work as well as work out how best to present it.

Answer (score 1):

> I thought `git add` is enough to log the modifies made before `checkout` to another branch.

This is not the case.

Git is, at its heart, all about *commits*.  A commit is a numbered entity—it has a unique *hash ID*, that random-looking string of letters and digits such as `30cc8d0f147546d4dd77bf497f4dec51e7265bd8`.  Git uses the hash ID to *find* the commit in its "objects" database, which stores the commits and various supporting objects needed to make the commits actually work.  Each commit stores two things:

- a full snapshot of all of your source files (in a special, read-only, Git-only, compressed and de-duplicated format so that making hundreds of commits doesn't take much space at all—most of the files are de-duplicated), and
- some metadata: information about the commit itself, such as the name and email address of the author of the commit, and some date-and-time-stamps and so on.

Commits are mostly permanent—you can get rid of a commit by just making it so that you can't *find* it unless you've memorized its hash ID, and then Git will (after a lot of time) eventually discard the commit entirely—and completely read-only.  Being read-only, though, and in a format that only Git can read in the first place, you literally can't actually *use* a commit at all!  This means that for you to use a commit, Git has to *extract* a commit.

Most version control systems behave this way.  That is, you say "I'd like to work on commit XXXXX" (for some hash ID—in Git, you will normally use a branch name here, but that translates *into* a hash ID internally)—and the version control system says *OK, let me go find and extract the archive that is stored under that ID*.  In traditional version control systems, ten minutes later or so you have a version you can work on / with.  You do your work and then you run their "commit" verb and wait another half an hour for them to make a commit.

With Git, you say "extract the commit" and milliseconds (or maybe a few seconds) later you have the commit and can start work.  But you can't just run `git commit` when you're done working: instead, Git makes you run `git add` *first*, and *then* run `git commit`.<sup>1</sup>  The important question is not "do I have to do this", but rather rather "*why* do I have to do this?"  The answer lies in Git's *index* or *staging area*.  **Git requires that you be aware of what the index is and does for you.**

---

<sup>1</sup>In some cases, you can run `git commit -a`, but I don't recommend this because it skips right over the key reason you're using `git add` in the first place, and leaves you stranded when you hit one of the situations where `git commit -a` doesn't work (there are several of these; some depend on whether you use "pre-commit hooks" and how good someone was at *writing* a pre-commit hook, for instance).  It also means that you can't grasp why `.gitignore` sometimes doesn't work, what happens with `git stash`, and numerous other cases.

---

#### Git's index, aka staging area, aka cache

The thing that Git calls by three names—index, staging area, and (rarely these days) cache—has multiple purposes, but its *most important one*, the one you *really have to know at all times*, is this: the index or staging area holds your *proposed next commit*.

When you run `git commit`, Git builds a new commit in milliseconds or seconds, not the minutes or hours older version control systems tended to take.  The reason Git can do this is that the index *always holds the proposed next commit*.  When you run `git commit`, Git hardly has to do any work at all: it just takes all the files that are in the index *right then* and freezes them into a new commit.

What's in the index is hard to see, kind of on purpose.  There *is* a Git command that can list its content—`git ls-files`—but it's not one users will normally use; it's not very *useful*.  Here's a snippet of `git ls-files --stage` output, as run on the Git repository for Git:

```
[...]
100755 af5da45d2878e07ffe4586bfb8c1dc16134f9e95 0       Documentation/cmd-list.perl
[...]
100644 1fb1b2ea90c5953eb465d3b108c01f23fb442a32 0       commit.c
100644 21e4d25ce7878ab6463110b6b3104c7b99d159cb 0       commit.h
100644 c531372f3ff0f13839a2056568cbaa7fd37f98a8 0       common-main.c
100644 40dbfb170dabc5a43d1194bd2fb32fe1580ff980 0       compat/.gitattributes
100644 19fda3e877641c3c083618928c241351f1caaf91 0       compat/access.c
[...]
100644 8442bd436efeab81afc25db9d89da082638fcca4 0       xdiff/xtypes.h
100644 115b2b1640b4504d1b7eb1bc4dc1428b109f6380 0       xdiff/xutils.c
100644 fba7bae03c7855ca90aff3f238321581a91a6676 0       xdiff/xutils.h
100644 d594cba3fc9d82d94b9277e886f2bee265e552f6 0       zlib.c
```

For *every file that would go into a new commit* (if I made one right now), the index has one of the above entries.  This entry gives the file's mode—"executable" or "not executable", which for silly historical reasons is spelled `100755` or `100644`—and the file's name and the (hash ID of the) de-duplicated, ready-to-commit file content, among other information.  The `0` in last column before the file's name is the *staging number*, which in normal use is always zero.

So, if I were to run `git commit` right now, Git would use the files in the index to make a new snapshot.  Well, actually, it would complain:

```
$ git commit
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

because all the files in the index *match* all the files in the current commit!  (Git can tell this quite fast—just a few milliseconds—*because* the contents are all pre-de-duplicated, so the internal hash IDs all match.)

**What running `git add` on a file does is update the index / staging-area.**  That is, suppose I open up `Makefile` or `xdiff/xutils.h` in my editor and make changes to this file.  I write these changes out.  The *changes I made* go into the *working tree*, which holds the extracted files.  The working tree does not hold the committed files: those are in a special Git-only de-duplicated format and my editor and compiler can't even read them.  Nothing—not even Git itself—can *change* them.  But the working tree files are just ordinary everyday files, so everything can read and change those, including me and my editor.

If I *do* change them, though, I must *prepare an updated, de-duplicated copy to be committed*.  To do that, I must run `git add`.  The `git add` command *reads the working tree copy* and compresses it down and checks for duplicates:

- If there *is* a duplicate, `git add` makes a note of that while updating Git's index / staging-area.  The compressed copy `git add` made is no longer needed; it gets discarded.
- If there is no duplicate, `git add` makes a note of that while updating Git's index / staging-area.  The compressed copy `git add` made will be needed, but it's ready for committing now!

So in *either case* the index is *once again ready for the next commit*.  The `git add` command has merely *updated the **proposed** next commit* by updating the index aka staging area.

#### Running `git commit` saves what's in the index

If I now run `git commit`, Git will make a *new* commit, with the new (i.e., updated) snapshot I *prepared* by running `git add`.  This new snapshot will be saved forever—or rather, as long as the commit itself exists.  Git will add this new commit, with its new snapshot and metadata, to the database of "all Git objects".  (Any all-new files are now objects in the database as well, in their compressed format: they weren't duplicates.  If they had been duplicates, they wouldn't be all-new and `git add` would have re-used the old saved content.)

(The new commit then becomes the *latest* commit on the branch, in the usual fashion; we'll skip all the details here.)

This is why it takes at least two commands to make a new commit: `git add` *prepares* things, updating the proposed next commit, and `git commit` *turns the proposed commit into an actual commit*.  Until then, it's just a proposal.

Another way to look at this is that, at all times, there are *three* copies of each "active" file (assuming it's in the current commit):

- There's a frozen-for-all-time, unchangeable copy of some file in the *current commit*.
- For that particular file, there's a frozen-format (i.e., de-duplicated) copy in Git's index too.
- And, for that particular file, there's an ordinary, usable, read/write copy in your working tree.

What `git add` does is *copy the working tree version into the index*.

#### This explains how `git status` works as well

When you run `git status`, Git says things like:

```
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

Changes staged for commit:

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        modified:   file1

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   file2
```

What Git has done is to run *two* `git diff` operations:

- First, Git compared what is in the *current commit* to what is in Git's index / staging area.  Here, *every file matched except for `file1`*.  File `file1` is *different*.  So Git calls that one out as "staged for commit".  If I were to run `git commit` right now, the new commit would have a *different copy* of file `file1`, than the copy that's in the *current* commit.
- Then Git compared what is in the *index* to what is in my working tree.  Here, *every file matched except for `file2`*.  File `file2` is *different*.  So Git calls that one out as "not staged for commit".  Running `git commit` won't store the *updated* `file2` unless I run `git add` on it.  Instead, it will store the *unchanged* `file2` that's still there in Git's index.

Having listed these out, Git may go on to report *untracked files*.  An untracked file is simply *any file in your working tree that is not in Git's index*.  That's all there is to that, except for one extra feature.

#### `.gitignore`

Files that *aren't in Git's index* will, by definition, be *omitted from the next commit*.  That's clear now: we know that Git makes the new commit from what's in Git's index.  If the file isn't in the index, it won't be in the new commit.

Such a file is said to be *untracked*.  Running `git status` reports on this file.  But sometimes, an untracked file is untracked *on purpose* rather than by mistake.  For instance, if we use Python, Python builds `*.pyc` files and/or `*.pyo` files (Python3 puts them in folders named `__pycache__`, which keeps down the clutter a bit, while Python2 drops them all over the working tree).  We don't want to commit these files (it's a bad idea in general).  But we don't want `git status` to *whine* about them either.

To make `git status` shut up about untracked files, we can list the files' names or patterns in one or more `.gitignore` files.  These tell Git: *When I run `git status` and these files are untracked, don't whine!*  **This does not make the files untracked!**  It is the fact that the files aren't in Git's index that makes the files untracked.  If a file is *tracked*, listing it in a `.gitignore` has no effect.  This fact only makes sense when you understand what the index is doing.

Besides making `git status` shut up, listing file patterns in `.gitignore` allows us to use a short-cut: we can run `git add .` or `git add *` or `git add --all`, and Git will *not* add these files if they are untracked.  That is, we can use en-masse "add everything", and it will only add untracked files as *new* files in the index *if they would be complained-about*.

What this means is that `.gitignore` is the wrong name for this file: it should be called `.git-do-not-complain-about-these-files-when-they-are-untracked-and-when-they-are-untracked-and-I-use-an-en-masse-git-add-command-do-not-add-them-to-the-index-either`, or something like that.  But do you really want to type in this file name?  (No, you don't.)  So `.gitignore` it is.