# What's the difference between git add . and git add -A?

Tags: git, github

Are there some differences between `git add .` and `git add -A`?

Thanks.

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572549/difference-of-git-add-a-and-git-add: you cannot ask this question with this title without seeing the original question (23 votes) in the list of related questions made precisely to avoid this kind of duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git add` stages all modifications and any new files.

`git add -A` stages all modifications and any new files, and will also remove any which are no longer in the working tree. (It also spotted renames when I tried it.)