# how to do all of operation to the multiple files that are updated, created and deleted at one time

Tags: git

first, i created a local repository, then let us look this command of git.

```
$touch test1
$touch test2
$touch test3
$touch test4
$touch test5
$touch test6
$touch test7
$touch test8
$touch test9
```

modifying the file content of test1, test2, test3, and

```
$rm test5
$rm test6
$rm test7
$rm test8
```

So, i need to do all of operations before commit the changes, 
here's the question, how do i finish the operation with one command at one time, rather than change them one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git add -A
```

should be the right command for updating the index with new files, removed files and modified files.
See "[Difference of "`git add -A`" and "`git add .`"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572549/difference-of-git-add-a-and-git-add)".

Then one commit will record all your staged modifications.