# git add only modified changes and ignore untracked files

Tags: git, commit, gitignore, staging

I ran "git status" and listed below are some files that were modified/or under the heading "changes not staged for commit".
It also listed some untracked files that I want to ignore (I have a ".gitignore" file in these directories).

I want to put the modified files in staging so I can commit them.  When I ran "git add .", it added the modified files AND the files I want to ignore to staging.

How do I add only the modified files and ignore the untracked files if presented with the git status below.

Also, are my ".gitignore" files working properly?

```
$ git status
# On branch addLocation
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   someProject/path/domain/viewer/LocationDO.java
#       modified:   someProject/path/service/ld/LdService.java
#       modified:   someProject/path/service/ld/LdServiceImpl.java
#       modified:   someProject/path/web/jsf/viewer/LocationFormAction.java
#       modified:   someProject/war/WEB-INF/classes/message/viewer/viewer.properties
#       modified:   someProject/war/page/viewer/searchForm.xhtml
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       .metadata/
#       someProject/build/
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: if you've added the .gitignore file AFTER you've tracked files then the .gitignore file will not ignore files which are already being tracked. that could be an issue.

Answer (score 1212, accepted):

Ideally your `.gitignore` should prevent the untracked (and ignored) files from being shown in status, added using `git add` etc. So I would ask you to correct your `.gitignore`

You can do `git add -u` so that it will stage the modified and deleted files.

You can also do `git commit -a` to commit only the modified and deleted files.

Note that if you have Git of version before 2.0 and used `git add .`, then you would need to use `git add -u .` (See "[Difference of “`git add -A`” and “`git add .`”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16162511/6309)").

Comment: point of interest, this (`add -u`) doesn't add __only__ `modified` files, it also "adds" `deleted` ones.. something I'm currently trying to prevent.

Comment: To only add modified files, I usually go top the top directory of my repo and type `for fil in $(git diff --name-only --relative); do git add $fil; done`. If I were to use it a lot (I don't), I would just make an alias for this in my `~/.bashrc` file. This does, of course, only work in bash.

Comment: No definite answer, only "works-for-most-people" answers? I have to use another process to do this correctly? How is this not built into git add? It seems like such a common thing to want to do.

Comment: You may interested in adding already added files list: `git diff --name-only --cached | xargs git add`

Comment: *n.b.* the methods mentioned in these comments will fail if you have odd filenames (spaces, asterisks, what not).  To properly escape any strangely named files, use: `IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b"); for file in $(git diff --name-only); do git add "$file"; done`

Comment: How should exactly your gitignore hide untracked files?

Comment: `git add -u` is short for `git add --update` and `git commit -a` is short for `git commit --all`

Comment: What if I don't want to add untracked files. Just because I changed something locally doesn't mean I want to change it on remote.

Answer (score 130):

This worked for me:

```
#!/bin/bash

git add `git status | grep modified | sed 's/\(.*modified:\s*\)//'`
```

Or even better:

```
$ git ls-files --modified | xargs git add
```

Comment: You don't need grouping (\(\)) if you are not going to reuse the group, and \s left whitespace in front of the filename for me. Not that it will affect the end result in this case, but for sake of setting an example here's the sed command I used: sed 's/.*modified: *//'. Verified on Mac OS X 10.9.5.

Comment: @Samuel Grouping is nice when testing the expression. Then I can print the match inside square brackets to see that I am right.

Comment: @Ярослав your solution adds modified and untracked files and is equal to `git add -u`, so it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: --modified seems to include deleted as well as just modified

Comment: git diff-files -z --diff-filter=M --name-only | xargs -0 git add --dry-run seems to work well.

Comment: @user877329 - You can loose the `grep` before the `sed` by only printing lines that match: `git ... | sed -n 's/.*modified:\s*//p' _(and I found it educational to see the grouping, I didn't realise they were the same as vim's default regex)_.**Tested  on OS X and Cygwin**

Comment: @TomášZato It requires Bash, which is available for Windows, either through Cygwin, or GNUWin32. However, the expansion of the sedpipe may result in a longer command line than Windows can support (due to API limitations). Also, it should be noted that the command will fail if any filename contains whitespace, on any platform.

Comment: I used to do this `git status -uno -s | cut -d ' ' -f 3 | xargs git add`  :joy

Comment: if the file name is `deleted` then it shouldnt work?

Comment: @DMart - Caution: `git diff-files -z --diff-filter=M --name-only` puts NUL between file names; this may not play well what you pipe it to.

Answer (score 64):

To stage modified and deleted files:

`git add -u`

Where `-u` is short for `--update`.

Answer (score 20):

```
git commit -a -m "message"
```

-a : Includes all currently changed/deleted files in this commit. Keep in mind, however, that untracked (new) files are not included.
-m : Sets the commit's message

Comment: Or simply `git commit -am "message"`.

Answer (score 9):

I happened to try this so I could see the list of files first:

```
git status | grep "modified:" | awk '{print "git add  " $2}' > file.sh

cat ./file.sh
```

**execute:**

```
chmod a+x file.sh
./file.sh
```

**Edit:** (see comments)
This could be achieved in one step:

```
git status | grep "modified:" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs git add && git status
```

Comment: This could be achieved in one step: `git status | grep modified | awk '{print $2}' | xargs git add && git status`

Comment: Yeah I  should I have provided that solution as well, thanks, I updated the post.

Comment: Best answer IMO. Allows for targeted addition, scoured the `git-add` man-page without anything that could achieve this in a simple manner like suggested in this answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

> I want to put the modified files in staging so I can commit them

**TL;DR : START**

Use interactive mode (`git add -i`), select update (type `2` or `u` in `What now> prompt`), select all(type `*` in `Update>>` prompt), exit interactive mode(type `7` or `q` in `What now> prompt`) .

**TL;DR : END**

**For the more patient:---**

**STEP 1**

You could use the interactive mode.

```
git add --interactive
```

or
the short-hand form,

```
git add -i
```

This will give a list of all modified files along with their status, plus a bunch of command options you could use, like:

```
           staged     unstaged path
  1:    unchanged       +17/-0 package-lock.json
  2:    unchanged        +2/-0 package.json
  3:    unchanged       +2/-28 src/App.js
  4:    unchanged        +7/-6 src/App.test.js

*** Commands ***
  1: status       2: update       3: revert       4: add untracked
  5: patch        6: diff         7: quit         8: help
What now>
```

**STEP 2**

For your case, type **u** or **2** against `What now>`,

```
What now>u
```

You get below,

```
           staged     unstaged path
  1:    unchanged       +17/-0 package-lock.json
  2:    unchanged        +2/-0 package.json
  3:    unchanged       +2/-28 src/App.js
  4:    unchanged        +7/-6 src/App.test.js
Update>> *
```

**STEP 3**

In the `Update>>` prompt, type `*` to add all the files of the above list to the staging area(you could well add individual files too by providing the comma separated numbers),

```
Update>> *
```

At this point of time, all of your modified files have been added to the staging area and you can verify the status by typing `1` or `s` in the `What now>` prompt(or just exit the interactive mode by typing `q` or `7` and run the usual `git status` command),

```
What now> 1
```

which will show you the status,

```
           staged     unstaged path
  1:       +17/-0      nothing package-lock.json
  2:        +2/-0      nothing package.json
  3:       +2/-28      nothing src/App.js
  4:        +7/-6      nothing src/App.test.js
```

We can see here that the **unstaged** column displays the text **"nothing"** for all the files of the list.

For the second part of question regarding ignoring the untracked files, I believe this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1274447/2915738) will help a lot.

Answer (score 4):

You didn't say what's currently your `.gitignore`, but a `.gitignore` with the following contents in your root directory should do the trick.

```
.metadata
build
```

Comment: I was using my .gitignore all wrong.  I had an empty .gitignore file in every directory that I wanted to ignore instead of having a single gitignore with contents in it.

Comment: @Steve: This would work if each .`gitognore` contained a start (ignore everything). But a single `.gitignore` in the top directory is usually much simpler to use and suffices.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is a feature or a bug but this worked for us:

`git commit '' -m "Message"`

Note the empty file list ''.  Git interprets this to commit all modified tracked files, even if they are not staged, and ignore untracked files.

Comment: This definitely does *not* work when using --amend.

Answer (score 1):

```
git add $(git status --short | grep '.M ' | sed 's/.M //')
# Change the regex pattern of grep only.
# So, if you create a custom shell alias or function, 
# the regex pattern of grep should be the parameter.
```

`.` is any one character in regular expression.
The short form consists of X and Y fields and a file name. eg: `XY filename.py`

Check the 'Short Format' section in the `git-status` manpage to select files precisely.

`M example.py`: Empty staged changes in the X field and unstaged changes in the Y field.

`MM example.py`: Staged changes in the X field and unstaged changes in the Y field.

Answer (score -4):

**git commit -am "your message here"** this worked for me