# git add . or -A is adding .gitignore file in commit list, how to get ridoff this?

Tags: git, github, gitignore, git-commit, git-add

If I change a bunch of files and then run command `git add .` it includes all the files along with `.gitignore` in my commit list.

If I use `git rm --chached .gitignore` then it is showing as `deleted: .gitignore` and `git add .` is adding the deleted `.gitignore` file

How can I IGNORE `.gitignore` itself so that `git add .` command adds only my changes in actual files or directories.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124726/git-add-only-modified-changes-and-ignore-untracked-files

Answer (score 5):

First of all, why would you want to ignore the file, it is supposed to be checked in.

If you want to ignore it, you can enter it into `.gitignore` itself, but it is probably better to handle local ignores differently: don't put them into the workspace `.gitignore` (but `.git/info/exclude` or globally define a exclude file for all repos (but outside the workspace): `git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore`).

Besides that, if the file is not tracked you can remove it with `git reset HEAD -- .gitignore`.