# How not to stage the untracked files in git?

Tags: git

At the time I get the `status`, it prints like this in the console.

```
$ git status
On branch easy_buy_and_sell
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/easy_buy_and_sell'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:  xyz/src/main/java/com/draglet/domain/order/LocalOrderImpl.java

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        log/
        production/

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Now, when I execute the `git add .`, it staged all the files in the `log/` and the `production/` folders. What can I do for not staging the untracked files?

Comment: create a git ignore file https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124726/git-add-only-modified-changes-and-ignore-untracked-files

Comment: @Andre thanks. I believe this is better solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `git add .` use `git add draglet-common/src/main/java/com/draglet/domain/order/LocalOrderImpl.java`

Because `git add .` stages all the files in working directory.

You can stage individual files by using `git add path/to/file1 path/to/file2`

You can use `git add -u path/to/file1 path/to/file2` to stage  modified and deleted files.

Comment: How can you stage a deleted file if this not in the workspace anymore?

Comment: After deleting a file, If you do `git status` then it shows the file was deleted. Now if you do `git add deleted/file` It means that this file won't present in staging area . Now if you commit it then the file wont be there in your commit.