# how to get files using scripting

Tags: python-3.x, git, shell, scripting

how to get a file name using git, well I want add file name automatically, for example bellow:

```
git ls-files -m # show me just files affected with changes
example/example.py
```

and I want to loop all my project, and get a name files and put that name in a string like bellow:

```
example.sh
# first check status
git status
# show files affected
git ls-files -m
echo "your changes in files $(git ls-files -m)" 
# add files
git add .
# add var name files
NAME_FILES = git ls-files -m # NOT WORKING
# add commit
git commit -m "files added $(NAME_FILES)" # but this line not working
```

when I show logs just display "files added  " and not display names files added.

please help me

thanks

Comment: you should add your files in staging area those file which is modified and then do commit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to [add modified files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7124760/6309)

```
git add -u
```

But if you do a git ls-files *after* the `git add` step, then you needs ([using this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15580184/6309)):

```
NAME_FILES=$(git status --porcelain|tr '\n' ' ')
git commit -m "files added ${NAME_FILES}"
```

Comment: sorry for the confusion, but I need is save a name file in a var and put that name into the git commit, like this:   "NAME_FILES = git ls-files -m and when commited like this git commit -m "your files affected in $(NAME_FILES)"".

Comment: @AngelOmarRojasPacheco OK. I have edited the answer accordingly.