# New git init and push to new remote repository

Tags: git, github

I have a user who has downloaded the content from a repo (aka she has the files from the repo locally already).

What we need is for her to be able to only push her local changes to a new Github repo but when we run `git add .` it adds all the files and tries to push them on her first push.

We've tried a number of things including mentioned here: [git add only modified changes and ignore untracked files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124726/git-add-only-modified-changes-and-ignore-untracked-files) but `git add -u` doesn't seem to be working on a folder.

So my question is how do I achieve the following:

1. `git init` a folder
2. git add all files (which already exist on the repo)
3. git commit -a -m (but only files that are changed locally)
4. git push to a new remote origin but *only the local changes* not all files

Our previous tests pushed all files to the repo which already exist which we don't want.

I think we're on the right track but as the files already exist we want to only detect the local changes.

Comment: Why does the user have a copy of the files without having a local clone of the repository?

Comment: It is a clone but we ran it previously and did a cache clean which broke things so were trying to just not have to rebuild things.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit complicated since you do not have the current status (HEAD of your origin branch) in your local git repo.

So the first goal is to get to that state.

The easiest way would be the following:

1. clone the repo properly into a new folder `git clone <your-repo-url> my-repo.new`
2. copy over all files from the directory with their changes
3. check `git status`, you should now see all their changes as diff
4. optionally: create a new local branch using `git checkout -b <some-branch-name>`
5. proceed with `git add .` and `git commit -m "some commit message"`

Comment: So just to confirm: a) steps 2-5 are in the new repo and b) don't we need to copy some of the new files/copy back to the current folder?

Comment: yes steps 2-5 are in the new repo. b) I just assumed you would continue to work in the new repo. (or remove the old folder and rename the new folder -with repo-)