# Git commit -a "untracked files"?

Tags: git, git-commit

When I do a `git commit -a`, I am seeing the following:

```
  # Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
  # with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
  # On branch better_tag_show
  # Changes to be committed:
  #   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
  #
  # modified:   ../assets/stylesheets/application.css
  # modified:   ../views/pages/home.html.erb
  # modified:   ../views/tags/show.html.erb
  # modified:   ../../db/seeds.rb
  #
  # Untracked files:
  #   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
  #
  # ../assets/stylesheets/
  # ../views/pages/
```

What does those untracked files mean? All the changes have been indeed tracked. I don't understand why git is warning me about untracked files here.

**EDIT**:

Ok I see a lot of confused replies. This is what happens after I `git commit -a` this.

```
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

As you can see, there is NOTHING other than those four files that had changes applied.

My question should be rephrased as follows: **Why is git warning me about untracked files when all of the changes in this commit has been tracked?**

In other words, **is the untracked warning in the git commit message *unnecessary*?**

Comment: `(use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)`

Comment: zengr that is not necessary because git commit -a will commit all changes to files that have been tracked.

Comment: It *is* necessary when the files have never been `add`ed till now. From the docs for `-a` : *Tell the command to automatically stage files that have been modified and deleted, but **new files you have not told git about are not affected**.*

Comment: Why do you say git is 'warning' you ? As I see it the 'untracked' files message is  informational. It is for you to see if those files need to be managed and act accordingly.

Comment: @sateesh Well whatever you want to call it I still don't think this is really helpful at all. How is this informative? What am I supposed to do? Did you read my post on the "EDIT" section where I wrote there is no modification on any other file except for those listed above? If you find this informative, it's equivalent to me telling you that any random folder on your repo tree won't be tracked when there is nothing to worry about.

Comment: `The problem isn't that Git is to hard, it's that smart developers are impatient and have exactly zero tolerance for unexpected behavior in their tools.` : http://teddziuba.com/2010/08/too-smart-for-git.html

Comment: Do you know about `.gitignore` ? You probably need such a file!

Comment: 0

Make sure you're in the right directory (repository main folder) in your local git so it can find .git folder configuration before you commit or add files.

Comment: The warning is unnecessary, but it just lets you know that `git commit -a` doesn't add untracked files.  Apparently people are getting tripped up by this, hence the warning/info?

Answer (score 132):

For others having the same problem, try running

`git add .`
which will add all files of the current directory to track (including untracked) and then use

`git commit -a` to commit all tracked files.

As suggested by @Pacerier, one liner that does the same thing is

`git add -A`

Comment: `git commit -a` will commit all tracked files, not track untracked files.  `git add .` will track untracked files in the current directory.  `git add -a` will track all untracked files.

Comment: @matteo it's `git add -A`, not `git commit -A` . As far as I can tell, there is no switch you can pass to `git commit` that includes untracked files.

Comment: -a seems to be deprecated for just A now.  Thank you, all the same. :)

Comment: For further insight on those commands, you can check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572549/difference-between-git-add-a-and-git-add

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `git add .` won't add any files you've manually specified in your `.gitignore` file, which means you can finely control which things are (not) added automatically with `git add .`.

Answer (score 38):

`git commit -am "msg"` is not same as `git add file` and `git commit -m "msg"`

If you have some files which were never added to git tracking you still need to do `git add file`

> The “git commit -a” command is a shortcut to a two-step process. After
>   you modify a file that is already known by the repo, you still have to
>   tell the repo, “Hey! I want to add this to the staged files and
>   eventually commit it to you.” That is done by issuing the “git add”
>   command. “git commit -a” is staging the file and committing it in one
>   step.

Source: ["git commit -a" and "git add"](http://lostechies.com/jasonmeridth/2009/09/10/quot-git-commit-a-quot-and-quot-git-add-quot/)

Comment: but , as you said 
git commit -a = git add . + git commit

why wouldn't it auto-add the file to the tracking area??....

Comment: @Johnny: `git commit -a` is not equal to `git add .` + `git commit`. The `git add` step adds *only the files which are listed as modified* in your `git status`, not everything in the current directory.

Comment: Yeah, I discovered that today!

Answer (score 25):

You should type into the command line

```
git add --all
```

This will commit all untracked files

Edit:

After staging your files they are ready for commit so your next command should be

```
git commit -am "Your commit message"
```

Answer (score 17):

If you are having problems with untracked files, this 3-line script will help you.

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add -A
git commit -am 'fix'
```

Then just `git push`

Comment: This woks for me because I needed to untrack tracked files that I'm now ignoring.

Comment: what is this -A flag?

Comment: @Diego Adds all files in the whole workspace, except for ignored ones

Comment: ok, yes this is what I'll need from now on. It used to be that files that I started untracking wouldn't show up in my git status output

Answer (score 9):

1. First you need to add all untracked files. Use this command line:

   `git add *`
2. Then commit using this command line :

   `git commit -a` or `git commit -A`

Answer (score 7):

As the name suggests 'untracked files' are the files which are not being tracked by git. They are not in your staging area, and were not part of any previous commits. If you want them to be versioned (or to be managed by git) you can do so by telling 'git' by using 'git add'. Check this chapter [Recording Changes to the Repository](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository) in the [Progit](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) book which uses a nice visual to provide a good explanation about recording changes to git repo and also explaining the terms 'tracked' and 'untracked'.

Comment: +1 for the reference to progit. please update the URL to v2 https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2 and https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're in the right directory (repository main folder) in your local git so it can find .git folder configuration before you commit or add files.