# git commit -a -m (unable to use short hand notation)

Tags: git

I read in tutorial that you can use `git commit -a -m "comment"` as a short hand to

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "comment"
```

when I trying to run this command I am facing following issue

```
Ashishs-MacBook-Pro:ourfirstrepo atyagi$ git commit -a -m "adding second file"
On branch work
Untracked files:
(use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    sample2.txt
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

could some one please explain why git commit -a -m is not working

Comment: What tutorial? That's completely incorrect.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git commit -a "untracked files"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470547/git-commit-a-untracked-files)

Comment: For a good introduction to Git, I can recommend http://git-scm.com/book

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'git commit -a' adds all *tracked* files to the commit.
Because these files are untracked, you will have to explicitly add them once, before you can use the -a flag.

Answer (score 2):

The `-a` adds all of the tracked files only.  It ignores the untracked files.

http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-commit