# How to make git track new files, not just existing files?

Tags: git

Finally going to give up and ask for help. Having some git (windows) issues. If I make changes to an existing file,I can add-commit-push as usual. However, if I create a new file, git does not track it at all. Regardless of folder or extension. I am quite certain this is not a gitignore issue.

I've tried cloning a fresh instance.  Tried adding several file types.  No errors, git just doesn't seem to be aware of new files.

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: What happens when you `git add --all`?

Comment: This is normal behavior. `git` does not track files unless you tell it to (which makes sense, because you don't want `git` attempting to track all your build artifacts, for example). You must explicitly `git add` those things you wish to track.

Comment: What do you mean, not aware of new files? They don't show in "untracked files" section of `git status`? Then it's a .gitignore issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git commit -a "untracked files"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470547/git-commit-a-untracked-files)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev no, they don't show in untracked files.  I have looked in all the .gitignore files, and there is nothing out of the ordinary.  I'm thinking some kind of config issue??  I really don't know.

Comment: @cjaube i don't get any errors or anything.  just nothing gets added.

Comment: Have you looked in all `.gitignore` files with the command `it check-ignore -v -- a/new/file`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure first those new files are not ignored:

```
cd /path/to/cloned/repo
git check-ignore -v -- a/new/file
```

If not, then a `git status` should list them, you can then add and commit said new files.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Agreed: it was a typo. I was mentioning that command back in 2014 (https://stackoverflow.com/a/26908774/6309)

Comment: Thank you!  Can you please help me interpret what returned?  It says .gitignore:2:*

Comment: @Sco That means the second line of your .gitignore file is ignoring everything