# Git, adding changes to commit, difference between add and commit flags

Tags: git

Is `-a` in `git commit -a` equivalent to git `add . -A`?

Assuming i have the following aliases:

```
 12 alias gita='git add . -A'
 13 alias gits='clear; git status'
 14 alias gitlog='git log --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit'
 15 alias commit='git commit -a '

 16 alias check='gita;commit'  <--------------------------
```

When i say `check`, is there any redundancy happening when i both `add -A` and `commit -a`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`git add -A` is NOT equivalent to the `-a` flag in `git commit`. `git add -u` is. It adds changes to tracked files (including rms). `git add -A` also brings in untracked files.

Since `git add -A` is superset of `git add -u`, that is enough and you need not specify the `-a` in commit as well.

Also, <del>if the path is not given, it is assumed to be `.`, so the `.` is superfluous as well</del>.

Starting git 2.0 (mid 2013), you will need to add the path, or `git add -A` would operate on the full working tree.

See "[Difference of “`git add -A`” and “`git add .`”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16162511/6309)".

Answer (score 6):

Sort of. `git add -A` will match against the working tree and the index, adding new files, marking modified files and removing deleted files. `git commit -a` will stage only files that have been added or modified, but new files will not be added unless already specified in a prior `git add`

Answer (score 2):

> Is -a in git commit -a equivalent to git add . -A?

No it is not. git add . -u is.

> When i say check, is there any redundancy happening when i both add -A and commit -a

No git commit -a will simply add the remaining files by itself. In this case: none.