# How to commit and push all changes, including deletes?

Tags: git

How to commit and push all changes, including additions, editions, and file deletions etc in one command?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You will have to do [`git add -A`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/572660/275354) to add all files new files, changes and removed files.  Than follow that up with `git commit` and `git push`

Answer (score 19):

Use the following commands-

1. `git add -A` to add all files new files, changes and removed files.
2. `git commit -m "Your message"` to save the changes done in the files.
3. `git push -u origin master` to send your committed changes to a remote
   repository, where the local branch is named master to the remote
   named origin

Answer (score 4):

please follow these command 
git commit -am "message" (to add and commit in single command)
git push origin [branch Name]

Comment: `commit -a` updates existing files but it does not add new files. See `git help commit` or try it.

Answer (score 2):

[Combine](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/06/helpful-command-aliases.html) all needed separate commands in one [alias](http://blog.afoolishmanifesto.com/archives/1620)?!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the following
**`git commit -a`**

Comment: If there are new files not added to the repository yet, you still have to `git add` them.

Answer (score -1):

As I understand your question you are asking about "-u" option used as below which will add all already existing in repo entries (but no new ones):

```
git add -u
```

which accordingly to man pages:

> ```
>    -u, --update
>        Update the index just where it already has an entry matching <pathspec>. This removes as well as modifies index entries to match the working tree, but adds no new files.
>        If no <pathspec> is given when -u option is used, all tracked files in the entire working tree are updated (old versions of Git used to limit the update to the current directory and its subdirectories).
> ```