# GitHub not adding files

Tags: git, github

I wanted to add an Xcode project to an existing repository using the following:

```
 cd Test
 git add .
 git commit -m 'Adding initial files.'
 git push -u origin master
```

But in the repository I get a green arrow on the folder I just added, and I'm not sure why that is happening.

[image: This is what I'm getting like on the folder]

**EDIT:** Why does this kind of symbol occur usually? any idea??

**EDIT 2:** `git status` says `unable to create c:/.../.../.../index.lock : File exists`

Comment: What files/folders were added? Do you have any submodules?

Comment: xcode project.. No.. i just created a repository , added a readme file and then followed the method mentioned in my question.. but its giving that green arrow on my folder..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys. Although I still dont know what was the problem. I did it all a fresh. Created another repo and added these files again. It worked..!!

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

Do you have any files, or just the folder? Git will not add an empty folder.

Comment: @Sharanya, are you certain the files have been added to your local repository? What is the output of `git ls-tree -r HEAD .`?

Answer (score 1):

`git status` should tell you whether there are uncommitted commits left.

Please note that `git add .` [does not add deletes to the commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572549/difference-of-git-add-a-and-git-add). Use `git add -A` instead...

Comment: I tried this. it says "unable to create c:/.../.../.../index.lock : File exists              If no other git process is currently running, this probably means that a git process crashed in this repository earlier. Make sure no other git processes are running and remove the files manually to continue. "