# github not uploading new files I created

Tags: git, github

I'm a github noob but I'd like to use it because of the open source aspect.

I managed to follow the tutorial, fill a repository initially and upload the files from my eclipse android workspace. Now I have added a few more files and tried the following git commands in my ubuntu terminal.

```
cd Dropbox/android/workspace
git add .    //figured this would add the new files?
git commit -m 'changed a few things...'
git push origin master
```

No error messages anywhere and when I look onto the github website, I saw a folder .metadata with the commit message I entered above. The other folders didn't have this message. I looked for my new files but they were not on github.

Am I missing something terribly easy?

Here is the terminal output for:

```
git add -A
```

Nothing.

```
git commit -m 'blah'

[master 41642e3] new fiels
 16 files changed, 57 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/Finance_Calculator2/.markers.snap
 create mode 100644 .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/Finance_Calculator2/.syncinfo.snap
 delete mode 100644 .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/Finance_Calculator2/org.eclipse.jdt.core/state.dat
 create mode 100644 .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/MyCalcFinance2/.markers.snap
 create mode 100644 .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/MyCalcFinance2/.syncinfo.snap
 delete mode 100644 .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/MyCalcFinance2/org.eclipse.jdt.core/state.dat
 create mode 100644 .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/TabletCalc/.markers.snap
 create mode 100644 .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/TabletCalc/.syncinfo.snap
 delete mode 100644 .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/TabletCalc/org.eclipse.jdt.core/state.dat
 create mode 100644 .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/blank/.markers.snap
 create mode 100644 .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/blank/.syncinfo.snap
 delete mode 100644 .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/blank/org.eclipse.jdt.core/state.dat
 create mode 100644 .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.root/.markers.snap
 create mode 100644 .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.snap
 create mode 100644 .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.team.cvs.core/.running

git push origin master

To https://github.com/killerpixler/Android-Application-Development.git
   bb1d6a5..41642e3  master -> master
```

Comment: Putting your Git repository in a Dropbox directory is generally a bad idea; Dropbox can corrupt the repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `git add -A` instead of `git add .`. Since your code is located in directories under the current directory, I'd assume git add . only adds the directories in the current directory, but it's not recursive and does not add the files below these directories.
`git add -A` will add all the changed files. You can exclude some files from being add with the `-A` option by creating a `.gitignore` file that explicitly says what's not to be added (i.e the `/bin` and `/gen` directories).

Comment: I did, again no errors but it still doesnt work. (i did the add, commit, push)

Comment: can you post what's print in the terminal when invoking `add,commit,push`

Comment: That's incorrect. `git add .` is recursive. And `git add -A` is short for `git add .; git add -u`. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572549/difference-of-git-add-a-and-git-add

Comment: got it to work... turns out that eclipse was stupid and put that project into a different folder that wasnt in the repo... therefore git didnt have anything new to push :)  thanks thou

Answer (score 0):

If it's an empty folder you're talking about - this is normal [git](/questions/tagged/git) behavior. [git](/questions/tagged/git) by default, will not add empty folders. You could force it to do so by following these steps:

Create a file named `.gitignore` inside the empty directory, with the following two lines:

```
# Ignore everything in this directory
*
# Except this file
!.gitignore
```

Comment: it is not. I created new .java files in my android project and want to push them to github

Comment: Try adding the files explicitly: `git add DIR/*.java` then checking the status with `git status`. If you get "nothing to commit" as response, check the log `git log DIR/FILE.java`. It will only say "nothing to commit" if this file is already committed.

Comment: Do check what branch you're currently using: `git branch`. It should display `* master` which means, the starred branch (master) is currently enabled - as should be the case.