# How to modify git add to handle deleted files?

Tags: git

I removed a few files from my git repo and now, upon status see

```
# Changes not staged for commit:
# ...
#   deleted:    project/war/favicon.ico
#   deleted:    project/war/index.html
```

Usually, i would stage them by issuing `git add .` command, but doing so does not affect git status. Files are still not staged for commit.

Now .. i know i can `git rm file` to take care of this.

The question is ... can i modify `git add .` somehow to also stage deleted files  as well? I thought add "." takes care of everything (deleted files included)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

`git add .` will add new and modified files to the index.  `git add -u` will delete files from the index when they are deleted on-disk and update modified files, but will not add new files.  You need a combination of the two:

```
git add . && git add -u .
```

Addendum: It appears that the `-A` switch will catch all three: added, modified, and deleted files.

```
git add -A .
```

Note the extra '.' on `git add -A` and `git add -u`

---

Warning, starting git 2.0 (mid 2013), `git add -A|u` (not extra dot) will *always* stage files **on the all working tree**.
If you want to stage file only under your current path with that working tree, then you need to use

```
$ git add -A .
```

See "[Difference of “`git add -A`” and “`git add .`”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16162511/6309)".

Comment: What if I don't want to add all files, only the deleted one?