# Unable to add deleted files to index after git branch merge

Tags: egit, git-merge-conflict

In an Eclipse (Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)) java project, I merged two branches and resolved all conflicts, getting no compilation errors and all tests to pass.

However, EGit (4.9.2.201712150930-r) won't let me add deleted files to the index/stage. The button for doing so is enabled, but nothing happens when I press it.

As a result, the conflicts regarding these files are not resolved (adding to the index is required for that), so I cannot proceed with a merge commit.

The situation is as in the figure below.

What do I need to do to resolve these conflicts?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not solve this problem with EGit, but closing Eclipse and running

```
git add -A .
```

in the command line solved the problem (opening Eclipse again immediately showed the files to be staged). (This solution came from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12824031/3358488).)

So not sure this is an EGit bug or if I just didn't know how to take this step using it. However, like I said, using the command line solved the problem.