# Difference between ( git add -A followed by git commit ) and git commit -a?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-add

`git add --all` or `git add -A` followed by `git commit -m "commit message"` seem to produce a different result from `git commit -am "commit message"` when I thought they would produce the same final result.

Am I doing something wrong with `git commit -am "commit message"`?

Also is `git commit -a -m "commit message"` the same as `git commit -am "commit message"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `git add -A` will add new files (as well as deleted and modified files)
  See "[Difference of “`git add -A`” and “`git add .`”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572549/difference-of-git-add-a-and-git-add)" for more.
- `git commit -a` will *not* add new files: it will only stage files that have been modified and deleted.

More generally, I always recommend to add first, check the status, and *then* commit.
I find that extra step a good opportunity to:

- check that nothing had been forgotten for the next commit
- check that no *extra* elements are added for the next commit (which shouldn't be part of it, being not ready)
- polish the commit message (I usually `git commit -f file`)

And yes, `git commit -a -m "commit message"` is the same as `git commit -am "commit message"`.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13573/why-use-superflous-dash-to-pass-option-flags-to-tar is an interesting read regarding unix-style for parameters.