# Git add not adding files

Tags: git, git-commit, git-add

when I try to git add my files, I typed

```
git add <insert file names here>
```

That works correctly. However, when I try to do

```
git commit -a
```

My git repository tells me that it's empty. What is outputted is:

```
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed) 
#
<insert name of files here>

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Might anyone know the solution to this? Thanks.

Comment: It could also already be a tracked file.

Answer (score 25):

And you may also want to make sure you're in the root of your project. I had that problem for a while on a Rails project a while back & then realized I was in the `/config` directory. Whoops! #noobmistake

Comment: Git works from anywhere in the git working tree. . .

Comment: @meawoppl It never has for me before, but I appreciate the downvote!

Comment: @meawoppl No. Git theoretically works from everywhere, but `git add --all` may not! I think the reason is that it's equivalent to `git add .` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572549/difference-between-git-add-a-and-git-add), and thus only works for the current and sub-directories. Please only downvote if you have well-funded knowledge on the subject...

Comment: same happened with me when executing `git add -u` command thanks for the notice

Answer (score 9):

The `-a` flag to `git commit` overwrites your staging area ("index"). Look at what the man page says:

```
   -a, --all
       Tell the command to automatically stage files that have been modified
       and deleted, but new files you have not told git about are not
       affected.
```

A rule of thumb is to use a plain `git commit` when you have used `git add`. The command `git commit -a` is for when you want to commit every change in the repository but can't bother to `git add` them.

PS. `git add -A` is useful: it adds all non-ignored new files in your working tree