# Git: only stage modified files, not removals or additions

Tags: git

As indicated in the [documentation](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-add.html) (and the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572549/difference-of-git-add-a-and-git-add)):

- `git -u` : adds modifications and removals to the index
- `git -A` : adds modifications, removals and additions to the index

Is there a 1-line git command that only adds file modifications, and not additions/deletions?

I want an easy way to add all of my edits, but don't want this action to add/remove files 
by default (I'll do that explicitly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could something like this:

```
git add $(git diff-files --diff-filter=M --name-only)
```

---

**Resources:**

- [git documentation - diff-files](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff-files.html)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you use

```
git add -p
```

it allows you to select changes interesting you.