# Github commit changes remotely

Tags: github

I cloned my repo and made some changes. I tried to push it to github:

```bash
git add *
git commit -m "changes"
git push origin master
```

but it hasn't found my changes. What can I do?

Comment: What do you mean you can't find your changes?  You can't find your commit?  Locally or remotely?  Have you tried `git status` or `git log` ?

Comment: You can refer this : http://media.pragprog.com/titles/tsgit/chap-005-extract.html

Answer (score 0):

Note that:

- `git add .` is the usual form to add everything in the current directory and subdirectories.
  (depending on your shell, '`*`' might not work as expected. A dot '`.`' will)
- `git add -u .` would allow you to record the *deletion* of files.
- `git add -A .` is a [shortcut to do both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572549/difference-of-git-add-a-and-git-add).

Comment: i tried. I made many changes to my sourcecode, but when i execute git push origin master, git said everythin up-to-date