# What does the 'git add .' ('git add' single dot) command do?

Tags: git, command-line-interface, git-add

I don't get what the Git command means, when adding files to the stage with the use of a period (or full stop, single dot):

```
git add .
```

What does this do?

Comment: The period in `git add .` means the current directory and all files within it, recursively. (The asterisk in `git add *`, on the other hand, would mean all files in the current directory except ones that begin with a period.)

Answer (score 101, accepted):

`git add .` adds / stages all of the files in the current directory. This is for convenience, and can still be used if you have certain files you don't want to add by using a `.gitignore`

A tutorial for `.gitignore` is located [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/gitignore).

A deeper look into `git add .` vs `git add -A` vs. `git add -u` is located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572549/difference-of-git-add-a-and-git-add?rq=1) and it might answer your question if you wanted more control of how you add all of the files / wanted to know how `git add .` works.

Comment: does `git add .` goes recursively or not? @agconti

Comment: Yes, `git add .` will add all files contained in the parent and children directories.

Answer (score 37):

`git add .` adds all modified and new (untracked) files in the current directory and all subdirectories to the staging area (a.k.a. the index), thus preparing them to be included in the next `git commit`.

Any files matching the patterns in the `.gitignore` file will be ignored by `git add`.

If you want to skip the `git add .` step you can just add the `-a` flag to `git commit` (though that will include *all* modified files, not just in the current and subdirectories).

Note that `git add .` will not do anything about deleted files. To include deletions in the index (and the comming commit) you need to do `git add -A`

Answer (score 4):

It adds all subsequent resources (on which you have made changes) under that folder to Git's version control for commit.

You should learn Git from this excellent walkthrough: *[Resources to learn Git](http://try.github.io)*

Answer (score 0):

In current versions of Git, this recursively adds all new, modified, and deleted files in the current directory to the index.

The period (`.`) is the standard way to refer to the [current directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) in many file systems (by contrast, "`..`" refers to the parent directory).  The [`add`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add) Git command adds the file contents to the index.  So `git add .` recursively adds all files in the current directory to the index.

As of Git 2.0 (added in 2014, a year after the question was asked), this will include new, modified, and deleted files.  Previous versions of Git [did not include deleted files](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#Documentation/git-add.txt-ltpathspecgt82308203):

> Note that older versions of Git used to ignore removed files; use `--no-all` option if you want to add modified or new files but ignore removed ones.