# Folder cannot be pushed to GitHub though it is absent there

Tags: git, github, pycharm

I've got a Django Project in PyCharm. I needed to make a repository on GitHub with this project - that's why i did next - VCS -> Import into Version Control -> Share Project on GitHub. Several times due to my "noobness" i was to delete project and repository both to start over. Today i perfomed that again and to my surprise found that PyCharm didn't push all the project folders to GitHub. I tried to add files to git manually like that "git add " but there is still no result. Structure of my folder tree is simple:

```
ProjectName_test:
   .idea
      scopes
   products
   ProjectName
   templates
```

Both folders - "templates" and "ProjectName" aren't pushed to GitHub. What should i do in this situation? Is there anything behind the scenes that doesn't let those folders to be pushed?

Comment: Git doesn't track empty directories. Put an empty `.gitignore` in them.

Comment: These directories are not empty. Both contain all the files that created automatically when making a new Django Project in PyCharm.

Comment: i have the same problem. if i add 1 new folder and 1 new file, adding the file adds the folder. i personaly do it in terminal. cd proj_dir/folder git add . , then i push it in pycharm [*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16969768/what-does-git-add-git-add-single-dot-command-do)

Answer (score 2):

Do the folders contain anything? Empty folders are ignored by Git.

Answer (score 0):

Which color are the files in that directories?

In case they are red that folders are not added to GitHub (you should right-click->Git->Add).
In case they are green you should first commit everything that you need (did you do that (?) right-click->Git->commit file) and after that (they are black) you could push your changes (right-click->Git->Repository->Push).

Please tell if it helps.