# Any difference between git add . and git add --all?

Tags: git, git-add

Is there any difference between:

```
git add .
```

and

```
git add --all
```

?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between "git add -A" and "git add ."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572549/difference-between-git-add-a-and-git-add)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`git add --all` will add the deleted file too (*removing files from index that are no longer in the working tree*), while `git add .` does not.

For new files and files already tracked in current working tree:

```
git add .
```

For only files already tracked in current working tree:

```
git add -u
```

For new files, files already tracked in current working tree, and remove files from index that are no longer in the working tree:

```
git add -A
```

or

```
git add --all
```

Comment: Nit pick: it can't "add" the deleted files.  It removes them.

Comment: @AdrianRatnapala:add the deletion of these files to the index.

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer is valid for Git 1.x.
But for Git versions from 2.0 and above, following is the difference:

```
git add .
```

> Adds, modifies and removes index entries/files in the **current directory and 
>   its subdirectories.**

While

```
git add -all
```

And

```
git add -A
```

> Adds, modifies and removes all index entries/files to match the **entire working tree** of the repository.

Refer [Git documentation for git add here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#Documentation/git-add.txt---all).