# Git locally not synced with remote after a "git reset --hard #commit"

Tags: git, github, git-commit

I am new to `git`. I don't actually use it for any project but just as a storage for all my dotfiles.

I did a `git commit` and just after that, I realised that was just unnecessary because it was an incomplete change. So, instead of doing another edit, `commit` and `push`, I reset the last good commit using `git reset --hard #commit_shaN` and pushed it to remote with help from here : [Git reset --hard and a remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377845/git-reset-hard-and-a-remote-repository). Remote is fine now but locally when I make new changes and try to do new commits, it says :

```
    On branch master
    Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

    Untracked files:
         blah
         blah
         blah
         blah
         blah
         blah
    nothing added to commit but untracked files present
```

I searched the web for help and got this : [Git:nothing added to commit but untracked files present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33513174/gitnothing-added-to-commit-but-untracked-files-present). As this page says, I added those untracked files to `.gitignore` with no result. It still gives the same output. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you certain that you actually modified any tracked files?  Note that you didn't necessarily have to do a hard reset if you wanted to keep those partial changes.

Comment: Yeah, I modified them and no, I don't want to keep any changes that I made after that "good" commit.

Comment: Well according to Git you did not modify any tracked files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1/ git reset --hard #commit_shaN
```

remove your last commit and also remove change of last commit.

If you want to undo last commit or unstage last commit use soft instead of hard

```
git reset --soft HEAD~1/ git reset --soft #commit_shaN
```

Then add new changes and them rename commit(new commit) or commit again

**Untracked files**: You can remove the untracked file using these two commands

```
git clean -n
git clean -f
```

**Untracked folders**: You can remove the untracked folder using deleted them it's the only way to remove untracked folders.

```
rm -rf pathOfFFolder
```

write this command with **sudo** or run terminal/cmd as administration if permission issue is occured