# A git command for adding all changes to staging

Tags: git

Suppose I have three files, one, two, and three. After initializing git and adding it to a remote repo, I now delete two.txt and modify three.txt. So while adding and committing now I have to do "git rm two.txt" and then go for "git add ."

My question is, do we have a command that can take all changes to staging area? Basically something like "git " that will update everything to stating area instead of manually having to delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for:

```
git add -A
```

From git 2.0 onwards:

```
git add .
```

Comment: Thanks but I have a followup question. Does it mean that from git 2.0 onward both command do the same?

Comment: @VyprNoch - From 2.0 onwards, `"git add <path>" is the same as "git add -A <path>"`. But `git add -A` can be different from `git add .`, as `git add -A` operates on the entire repo, and `git add .`, obviously acts on the current directoy ( and children.)

Answer (score 2):

Use the following command

```
git add -A
```

Check out this question:

[Difference between "git add -A" and "git add ."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572549/difference-between-git-add-a-and-git-add)

Comment: Thank you for the article link but he answered before so I had to accept his answer.