# How to update the directory in git

Tags: git, git-commit

I have a bitbucket repository, with the following structure :

```
 Directory-A->
   directory a
   directory b
   file a
   file b
   file c
```

Now I want to move file "b" and file "c" to "directory a"

When I do it on local machine and commit this by git add.
I get file b and file c in directory a but they still exists outside it.

Comment: When you move files, you need to `add` the new ones (new location) but also `rm` the old ones (old location).

Comment: I have hundreds of files and I dont want to use rm for each one

Comment: `git add --all` may help you.

Comment: but it doesnt remove files from their previous prositions...is therea better way out than removing each one manually

Comment: is there a difference between git add --all and git add .

Comment: What? git add -A . would have done what Saurabh suggest. It does include git add -u

Comment: i didnt tried that...i vl try doing git add-A

Comment: Let me know how it works. I had the right answer *before* Saurabh

Comment: Again, `git -A` is `git add -u` + `git add`: What Saurabh said is exactly my answer. What is going on here?

Comment: Strange... Saurabh's account has been deleted... So, does `git add -A .` (or `git add -u .` + `git add .`) works?

Comment: Just to be sure: git mv is only valid if you haven't already moved your file. Again, if you have moved them, git add -A is the answer.

Answer (score 4):

> When I do it on local machine and commit this by git add. I get file b and file c in directory a but they still exists outside it.

That is because you did a `git add .` in `directory a` instead of a `git add -A .` in `Directory-A`.

First, you need to be in `Directory-A` (the root one) when you do the `git add -A .` (which is a `git add -u` + `git add .`) from the root folder:

```
Directory-A->  <====== there: git add -A .
   directory a
     file b
     file c
   directory b
   file a
```

A '`git add -A .`' in `Directory-A` will detect the deletion of those files in `Directory-A` and their addition in `directory a`.

See more at "[Difference between “`git add -A`” and “`git add .`”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/572549/6309)":

Answer (score 4):

Here is a better alternative.
Try the following:

```
git mv "file b" "file c" "directory a"
```

Followed by:

```
git commit -am "hey I moved filed"
```

**Note**: I've only used the `-am` flag for demonstration purposes. It is not a good practice. You should commit only files with related changes together which makes your repository maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do it like this, I believe it's even easier and will work for entire project:

1. Physically move files **b** and **c** into directory **a** (using file explorer or command line).
2. Run this Git command in your project:

   `git add -u`

   (it will auto remove all deleted files from Git index: since you moved your files physically Git will consider them 'deleted' from old location and created at the new one)
3. Now add all changed/created files to new commit:

   `git add .`
4. Commit changes as usual:

   `git commit -m "Moved files b and c into directory a"`

---

Here is more info on `git add -u` command (`-u` is a shorthand for `--update`):

> ... removes as well as modifies index entries to match the working tree, but adds no new files ... all tracked files in the entire working tree are updated ...

Source: http://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-add (look for **--update** section)

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix.  Run:

```
git add -A :/
git status
```

Then make sure that **only files you want to add/delete/modify have been staged**.  That's very important.  If you've accidentally staged extraneous changes, run `git reset`.  If you're sure you want to proceed, run `git commit`.

Without `-A`, `git add` only stages file additions and modifications.  It will not delete entire files, and moves will turn into copies.  `git add -A` deletes files that no longer exist.

`:/` is a shortcut that means the root of the repository, rather than the current directory.  If your current directory is the root of the repository, you can omit this.

*Note that running `git add -A`--especially in the root of a repository--is generally considered dangerous.  Do not get into the habit of blindly committing every change you've made: only stage what you know you want to change.  However, when you're moving a large number of files around, this is quite a handy utility.*

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

git mv "file a" "directory a"/

git mv "file b" "directory a"/

git commit -m "Files a and b are moved to directory a"

Happy Coding.