# Detecting deletion of "files" in git

Tags: git

I have some buggy third-party script, which generates some files, I want to put into *git*. Now, the script does work mostly fine but at times fails and deletes files (I know this is horrible, ...).

Now, I would like to detect, when a file removal is added to the index and filter that out. The only solution that I could come up with would be to do `git diff` and search for `deleted file mode` and backstep to the path. This does seem pretty ugly, though.

Is there a better way of filtering this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that a simple [`git add`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-add) only adds new or modified files, not deleted ones.
For that, you need a [`git add -u` or `git add -A`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16162511/6309).

That means you *could* consider doing only a `git add` after your script, and a commit.
Then a `git checkout HEAD -- .` would restore any deleted files.

Comment: Thanks. I before did `git add mydirectory`, which also did stage the deletes. With `git add mydirectory/*.file` it works fine.