# How to add multiple files in git for a single commit?

Tags: git, git-commit

I made changes to two files in different directory, How can I add the two files for a single commit. can I do like, add the first, then change the directory to second file and add the second file finally do the commit. Is this going to work?

Comment: You can add as many files as you like before committing them. I suggest completing the git tutorial to gain a better understanding of the steps involved https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1

Comment: What error message do you get when trying to follow the procedure you're proposing?

Comment: Yes! This is going to work!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can add all the files using

```
git add file1.txt folder/file2.txt file3.txt file4.txt file5.txt
```

And the commit your the files you wish to commit.

```
git commit file1.txt folder/file2.txt file3.txt -m"I committed file1.txt folder/file2.txt"
```

You will have added

- file1.txt
- folder/file2.txt
- file3.txt
- file4.txt

to staging area and then commited with the same message.

- file1.txt
- folder/file2.txt
- file3.txt

---

Note that files are added or committed in the same format

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `add` command [interactively](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Interactive-Staging):

```
git add -i
```

then you see:

```
*** Commands ***
  1: status       2: update       3: revert       4: add untracked
  5: patch        6: diff         7: quit         8: help
What now>
```

hit 4 (add untracked), then you see

```
What now> 4
  1: file1
  2: file2
Add untracked>>
```

hit 1 and 2 to add `file1` and `file2`

then you commit these files: `git commit`

Answer (score 7):

If the two directories are part of the same git project, just add the two files with `git` and then make your commit :

```
git add folder1/file1 folder2/file2 
git commit
```

With doing this, you can see that for this specific commit, you have two files which the contents are changed.

Comment: You can also add them in the same command `git add folder1/file1 folder2/file2`

Answer (score 4):

1."git status" list which files are staged, unstaged, and untracked.
Under "Changes not staged for commit" you can see all your edited files.

```
 git status
```

2."git add" to stage your commit.

```
 git add <file1> <file2> <file3>
```

(or)
"git add -A" to  stage all the modified files to commit.

```
 git add -A
```

3."git commit -m " to commit your changes,

```
 git commit -m "I am committing multiple files"
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option. You can add "ALL" the modified files to the next commit with

```
git add -A
```

which is equivalent to

```
git add -all
```

Then you can use

```
git commit -m "some info about this commit"
```

Useful when you have more than just two files or if you don't want to write the names/paths of them.

From:

[git-add Documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-add)

---

Also this question can give to you more info about git add:
[Difference between "git add -A" and "git add ."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572549/difference-between-git-add-a-and-git-add)