# How to add all files (added, modified, deleted) to index using JGit?

Tags: jgit

I am trying to use JGit to add all files to the index (stage area).

By doing `git.add().addFilepattern(".").call()` I get to add *modified* and *new* ones. But not *deleted* ones.

How to add all *deleted* ones as well?
I tried `git.add().addFilepattern("-u")` but it does not work.

**Related question** (about adding specific deleted files, not all deleted files):
 [How can I use JGit to add deleted files to the index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32876426/how-can-i-use-jgit-to-add-deleted-files-to-the-index)

Comment: If you only care about doing this in jgit, why did you include the tag [tag:git]? Why did you include the tag [tag:java] at all? (Note the text that pops up if you hover over the tags in your question.)

Comment: sorry, I removed them now

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [setUpdate(boolean)](https://download.eclipse.org/jgit/site/5.9.0.202009080501-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/api/AddCommand.html#setUpdate-boolean-) ?

```
// fair warning : not tested, I only read JGit's doc
git.add().setUpdate(true).call()
// or
git.add().setUpdate(true).addFilepattern(".").call()
```

Comment: actually i just managed to make it work. I played with it for a lot and figured out the following:  
`git.add().setUpdate(true).addFilepattern(".").call(); // stage modified and deleted`  
`git.add().addFilepattern(".").call(); // stage modified and new`  
So basically when you have both then you get _new_, _modified_ & _deleted_