# Git is not adding files

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am trying to add some files to the staging area. But git isn't responding. What am I doing wrong?

This is what I get when I am querying for the current status

```
(web) roy@desktopL:~/Workspace/kpr-admin-db$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        deleted:    .~lock.callLog.csv#
        modified:   db.sqlite3
        modified:   dbaccess/models.py
        modified:   dbaccess/models.pyc
        modified:   volunteers.csv

    Untracked files:
      (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        dbController.py

    no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

When I'm trying to add

```
(web) roy@desktopL:~/Workspace/kpr-admin-db$ git add *
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
dbController.pyc
Use -f if you really want to add them.
fatal: no files added
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all to add all files you have to use:

```
# add new, removed and updated files
# -A is alias for `git add . && git add -u`
git add -A .
```

---

#### Note

With [Git 2.0](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f99a38c0121456822f8a9dfb7928eefceaa98201/Documentation/RelNotes/2.0.0.txt#L32-L36), `git add -A` is default.

Copied from the above release notes:

> `git add <path>` is the same as `git add -A <path>` now, so that
>   `git add dir/` will notice paths you removed from the directory and
>   record the removal.  In older versions of Git, `git add <path>` used
>   to ignore removals.  You can say `git add --ignore-removal <path>` to
>   add only added or modified paths in , if you really want to.

---

In your case you have the file in your `.gitignore` file so you have to remove it from the file.

Answer (score 1):

Use the followings instead

```
git add .
```

or

```
git add --all
```

refert this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572549/difference-between-git-add-a-and-git-add)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add recently created, deleted and updated files, use 
`git add -A`

Note : `git add -A` do not add files which are mentioned in `.gitignore`. You have to remove it from there.