# Why are file deletions not staged by "git add --all *"?

Tags: git, file, version-control

When I run `git add --all *`, file deletions are not being staged. The output of `git status` shows the deletions in red under the heading "Changes not staged for commit". It is only picking up new additions, and not deleting stuff I have removed. What should I do?

Comment: Because when you write `*`, the shell expands that to all the files that exist in the current directory as of now. Git doesn't see the `*` (it sees a list of files), and never hears about the deleted files that you intended to select.

Comment: Thanks!  That fixed it

Comment: @Nayuki Could you please copy that comment into an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run `git add --all *`, the command shell expands the `*` wildcard into the list of file/directory names in the current working directory. The Git program never sees the `*`; it receives an actual command line like `git add --all foo.txt bar.jpg subdir`.

It is good that you are using the `--all` (or `-A`) flag, which tells Git to stage changes to files paths that are deleted. So all you need to do is to run `git add --all .`, which tells Git to look at the entire current directory (and all subitems recursively), add the ones that are created/modified, and also take into consideration items that were in the index but no longer exist in the working directory.

Comment: Helpful reference for `git add` flags: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26039014/839689