# Why does my commad "git add ." comman not work on git bash?

Tags: git, bash

```
$ git add.
Error:
git: 'add.' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Did you mean this?
    add
```

Whenever I try to add all sub directories using "git add." command ,it gives the above error.
And if I try "git add .",then the screen does not give any output(displays blank).
eg:
$ git add .

Comment: Error itself is saying the solution. There is no command as "git add." try doing "git add --all" or "git add <filename>"

Comment: you can see documentation https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add

Comment: `git add.` is not a command, nor is it a complete sentence.  You probably mean `git add .` with a space.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between "git add -A" and "git add ."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572549/difference-between-git-add-a-and-git-add)

Comment: you need space between `add` and `.`

Comment: "*And if I try "git add .",then the screen does not give any output(displays blank)*" That's because it worked. Git is the strong, silent, slightly mad type. If everything works, it won't tell you anything. Use `git status` to find out what's going on.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are not leaving a space between add and the period.
try: 
`git add .`
or 
`git add -A`

documentation for git:
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add

Comment: tried this too.does not work.

Comment: Try make a change.
type git status 
type `git add .`
then type git status again. you should see that the changes are now being tracked