# Is in Git 2.x `git add .` and `git add -A` are same?

Tags: git

In Git 1.x `git add .` does not include deleted files.But from Git 2.0 will it include?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct. [Reading the changelog for git 2.0.](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f99a38c0121456822f8a9dfb7928eefceaa98201/Documentation/RelNotes/2.0.0.txt#L32-L36)

> `git add <path>` is the same as "`git add -A <path>`" now, so that
>   "`git add dir/`" will notice paths you removed from the directory and
>   record the removal.
>   In older versions of Git, "`git add <path>`" used to ignore removals.
>
> You can say "`git add --ignore-removal <path>`" to
>   add only added or modified paths in `<path>`, if you really want to.

So executing

```
git add .
```

will include removed files.

To get the old behaviour of `git add` pre-2.0

```
git add --ignore-removal .
```

executing this will 'exclude' removed files from the add operation.

---

EDIT: I did some further googling around the topic and found [this wonderful answer that expands on what I said.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26039014/2344348)