# Linux Script to checkin a lot of repos at night

Tags: git

I have a ton of Repos (20+) that I am just starting out on.  I know this is not good practice in general,  but I am the only developer so far,  and I want to make sure I check in everything before I go to bed,  compilable or not just to save it.  No one else is using it now, so this is a temporary solution.  I have this script I wrote:

```
cd /asdf/code/My-Parent
git add *
git commit
git push
cd ../My-Parent-Core
git add *
git commit
git push
```

.... forever.   However,  it asks for a commit description,  which I have no problem making "Nightly Check in:  at first.  ( I would like to stress this is just a solution to a beginning of a project.)

Is there a way to add a commit message to my "git commit"  line so I can be sure that I saved everything before I go to bed?

Answer (score 4):

Use `git commit -m "your message here"` to add a commit message at the time of committing.

However, your method of using `git add *` won't take into account any files you've deleted. You can either also run `git add -u` or do both new and existing files using `git add -A`. [A nice answer on that can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572549/difference-between-git-add-a-and-git-add).