# Git commands work when executed but not by cronjob

Tags: bash, git, cron

Weird predicament I'm in here. I'm trying to run this code in a cronjob:

```
cd /home/justi180/public_html; git add *; git commit -m "Auto commit"; git push origin master;
```

When I run the above in a terminal myself it works. When I run it in a cronjob it doesn't work, however. The output of the cronjob when it tries to commit looks like this:

```
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   logs/popularity/daily.json
#       modified:   logs/popularity/monthly.json
#       modified:   logs/popularity/totals.json
#       modified:   logs/popularity/visitors.json
#       deleted:    thisisatest
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
```

I've additionally confirmed the job is running as my user by sticking a `whoami` at the front of the commands. I'm really not sure what to do here; the job is running as the right user and is clearly finding the `git` command to run, so my normal cron debugging isn't really taking me anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of executing git add * try this :

```
git add -u 
git add -A
```

Comment: Ahh, that was it. The wildcard must have been messing it up, eh?

Comment: yes, having * will only "add" the changes to the index but the deleted content will be ignored.

Have a look at this answer :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572549/difference-between-git-add-a-and-git-add

This explains the differences between -A -u * and . etc

Comment: Yeah I was aware just doing an "add" wouldn't remove deleted content. I was more wondering why the "add *" didn't work before but the "add -A" did, and I think it's because of the wildcard doing funky things in cron.