# Move directory to a new repo in github

Tags: git, github

Current repo looks like this...

```
/ab/docter
/ab/pepper
/cd/..
...
```

I want to keep the whole history in `ab` and move it to a new Repo in GitHub.

```
/doctor
/pepper
```

I tried to pull and manually move it to `ab` repo but the history doesn't come with the push. :(

Comment: What if you move all the files, commit that changes on a new branch and then rebase onto your master branch?

Comment: @KeukenkastjeXYZ that sounds like a plan... Could you note the actual commands to do so??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detach (move) subdirectory into separate Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-move-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository)

Comment: I would first create a new local branch from master: git checkout -b [name]

Then move the files and add them all: git add -A

Then commit the files: git commit -m '[message]'

Then push the branch to remote: git push origin [branchname]

Now your changes are on a separate branch on the remote. You can rebase or merge them into master. First checkout master: git checkout master

And then merge (or rebase, I prefer merging): git merge [branchname]

Everything should be in order now, see if your changes made it to your local master and then push master to the remote (git push)!

Comment: Resources used:
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging
https://github.com/Kunena/Kunena-Forum/wiki/Create-a-new-branch-with-git-and-manage-branches
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572549/difference-between-git-add-a-and-git-add
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use 'git subtree split'

```
git subtree split --prefix dir-to-extract -b selective-history
```

Source: https://cjohansen.no/git-subtree-multiple-dirs/

Comment: Thanks for the link. This is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

Checkout all branches then run:

`git filter-branch --tag-name-filter cat --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter ABC -- --all`

[Detach (move) subdirectory into separate Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-move-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository)

Comment: can you plz elaborate more??? The post doesn't explain much and doesn't make sense :( Pretty sure the command you gave me doesn't work.

Comment: Did you look at the link I attached? More than enough info in there.

Comment: It's tooooo complicated and I don't know how to apply it to my case :( Sorry

Comment: Clone a new copy of your repo. Checkout every bench you care about. Most likely all. `git filter-branch --tag-name-filter cat --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter ab/doctor -- --all` This will create a new repo containing ab/doctor. Set origin to a new bare repo. `git remote set-url origin PATH_TO_REPO.git` Then push. `git push -all` Push tags. `git push --tags`. Repeat for other directory