# Generate component and add it to git automatically

Tags: angular, git

In Angular CLI (2^),  I want to automatically generate component and add to git , how to achieve that knowing that I have to add every generated component manually ( using IDE or CMD) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between "git add -A" and "git add ."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572549/difference-between-git-add-a-and-git-add)

Comment: I want to add generated files with " ng g c components" to git automatically with the same command.

Comment: I also search for this opportunity

Comment: @АртурГудиев I remember there was a dialog asking me to add newly generated files to git for the current project. Try to update your IDE to latest versions. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IntelliJ IDE which I am using now detects all new added files and suggest to add them to git.